# distance cost calculator

Tags: php

Hello I am looking for a distance cost calculator like airports, taxi firms would have for example:

from x to xx it will cost ...

here is what i have made with help from some others here: http://pastebin.com/0pSF7VsA
however i cannot work out how to get it to work e.g. do the maths when the user selects it from the form.

here is my form so far: http://pastebin.com/sq14eYMQ

thanks

Comment: You should paste the relevant code inside of the question and highlight where you are having issues, and describe exactly what the issue is (parsing input, doing actual math calculations, etc). This will allow us to help you better with your question.

Comment: You should put the places/prices in an array, it would be so much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a clean up and an example of the calculations after post. hope it helps.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* places array, multi dimensional could also be used but noticed prices are the same  */
$data = array("Algeciras"=>10,"Almuñecar"=>20,"Alora"=>30,"Antequera"=>10,"Benahavis"=>15,
"Benalmadena costa"=>20,"Benalmadena pueblo"=>25,"Calahonda"=>30,"Cartama"=>40,
"Coin"=>12,"Estepona"=>15,"El Faro"=>20,"Frigiliana"=>16,"Fuengirola"=>30,"Gibraltar frontier - La Linea"=>12,
"Granada"=>30,"La Cala de Mijas"=>10,"La Cala Golf Resort"=>20,"Malaga"=>5,"Manilva"=>12,"Marbella"=>20,"Mijas Costa"=>7,
"Mijas Pueblo"=>20,"Nerja"=>10,"Puerto Banus"=>15,"Puerto de la Duquesa"=>10,"Rincon de la victoria"=>23,
"Ronda"=>20,"San Pedro de Alcantara"=>10,"San Roque"=>20,"Sierra Nevada"=>12,"Sotogrande"=>19,"Tarifa"=>20,
"Torre del Mar"=>30,"Torremolinos"=>10,"Torremuelle"=>14,"Torrenueva"=>18,"Torrox Costa"=>11);


/* number of people array */
$car=array('1'=>0,'2'=>50,'3'=>70,'4'=>90,'5+'=>110);


$now = date("H:i");
$cutoff = "18:56";

function rateOffset($now, $cutoff){
    if ($now < strtotime($cutoff)){
        // if less than 6:56pm add 20.00 20.00 euros to price
        return 20.00;
    } else {
        // if more than 6:56pm add only 6 euros to price
        return 6.00;
    }
}

//This is a basic example of how to check if the form was posted
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['to'])){

    if(isset($_POST['from']) && $_POST['from']=='Gibraltar'){
        /* places array to overwrite malaga prices   */
        $data = array("Algeciras"=>10,"Almuñecar"=>20,"Alora"=>30,"Antequera"=>10,"Benahavis"=>15,
        "Benalmadena costa"=>20,"Benalmadena pueblo"=>25,"Calahonda"=>30,"Cartama"=>40,
        "Coin"=>12,"Estepona"=>15,"El Faro"=>20,"Frigiliana"=>16,"Fuengirola"=>30,"Gibraltar frontier - La Linea"=>12,
        "Granada"=>30,"La Cala de Mijas"=>10,"La Cala Golf Resort"=>20,"Malaga"=>5,"Manilva"=>12,"Marbella"=>20,"Mijas Costa"=>7,
        "Mijas Pueblo"=>20,"Nerja"=>10,"Puerto Banus"=>15,"Puerto de la Duquesa"=>10,"Rincon de la victoria"=>23,
        "Ronda"=>20,"San Pedro de Alcantara"=>10,"San Roque"=>20,"Sierra Nevada"=>12,"Sotogrande"=>19,"Tarifa"=>20,
        "Torre del Mar"=>30,"Torremolinos"=>10,"Torremuelle"=>14,"Torrenueva"=>18,"Torrox Costa"=>11);
    }

    $rateCalc = rateOffset($now, $cutoff);

    echo $now." = $rateCalc<br />";
    echo "Price to {$_POST['to']} from {$_POST['from']}: ".number_format($data[$_POST['to']],2)."<br />";
    echo "Number of people price: ".number_format($car[$_POST['people']],2)."<br />";
    echo "Time rate calculator: ".$rateCalc."<br /><hr />";

    $total = number_format($data[$_POST['to']],2) + number_format($car[$_POST['people']],2) + $rateCalc." in euros<br /><br />";
    echo "Total: ".$total;

}else{
    echo '<form method="POST" action="">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="name" name="name" />

                    <label>From:</label>
                    <select name="from">
                        <option selected="selected">Malaga</option>
                        <option>Gibraltar</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <label>To:</label>
                    <select name="to">
             ';
    foreach ($data as $place => $price){
        echo "<option>{$place}</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <label>Date:</label>
                    <input type="text" value="dd/mm/yyyy" id="date" name="date" />

                    <label>Number of people:</label>
                    <select id="people" name="people">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5+</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <div id="return">
                        <label>Is this a return<br />journey?</label><div class="clr"></div>
                        <div id="radio-buttons"><input type="radio" name="return" value="Yes" class="radio" />Yes<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="return" value="No" class="radio" />No</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clr"></div>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="fauxButton" />
                </form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thats great Lawrence but how do I give a different price from Gibraltar for each of the locations.

Comment: @Graham Barnes as I went through it I noticed the prices are the same :s. Tho You could do a check within the if statement to see which pickup point was selected then set the data array from that choice.

Comment: sorry Lawrence but i know very little PHP, i put some dummy figures in so they will intact both be different values.